# Clojure, sum a list of vectors, recording positions along the way

Tags: recursion, vector, clojure, lisp, tail-recursion

Say I have a list of vectors

```
([0 0] [1 0] [1 0] [1 0])
```

I want to be able to add the list of vectors together and record each unique position along the way.

```
                [0 0]
[0 0] + [1 0] = [1 0]
[1 0] + [1 0] = [2 0]
[2 0] + [1 0] = [3 0]
```

Giving 4 unique positions.

```
([0 0] [1 0] [2 0] [3 0])
```

Any idea how I could achieve this in Clojure?

I've tried the following code, but it overflows for large number of vectors :(

```
(defn add-vectors [vectors]
  (let [[a b] vectors]
    (vec(map + a b))))

(defn get-positions [dirs positions]
  (if (empty? (rest dirs))
    (set positions)
    (do
      (let [next-pos (add-vectors (take 2 dirs))]
        (get-directions (conj (rest (rest dirs)) next-pos) (conj positions next-pos))))))
```

the `(conj (rest (rest dirs))` replaces the first element in the next recursive call with the sum of the first two vectors from the last call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add two numbers together, you can use the [`+`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/+) function, as you know:

```clj
(+ 2 1)
;;=> 3
```

To add two vectors together, you can use the [`mapv`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv) function to zip together the two vectors using `+`:

```clj
(mapv + [1 0] [1 0])
;;=> [2 0]
```

To perform a left fold of this vector addition across a sequence of vectors, you can use [`reduce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce):

```clj
(reduce #(mapv + %1 %2) [[0 0] [1 0] [1 0] [1 0]])
;;=> [3 0]
```

Or, replacing that function literal with a usage of [`partial`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial):

```clj
(reduce (partial mapv +) [[0 0] [1 0] [1 0] [1 0]])
;;=> [3 0]
```

To obtain all the intermediate steps of this left fold, you can use [`reductions`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reductions):

```clj
(reductions (partial mapv +) [[0 0] [1 0] [1 0] [1 0]])
;;=> ([0 0] [1 0] [2 0] [3 0])
```

Finally, to return only the unique elements from this sequence, you can use [`set`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/set):

```clj
(set (reductions (partial mapv +) [[0 0] [1 0] [1 0] [1 0]]))
;;=> #{[0 0] [1 0] [3 0] [2 0]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the eloquent response! It means a lot for someone trying to grasp the basics of Clojure